# How to make multiple PivotItems visible in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I have a Pivot table in sheet "Main". In `PivotField` "Report Filter" I have "Country Code" which contain 200 countries. I want to Make visible more than 1 countries from that filter using InputBox.

The problem is I need to choose minimum one country or ALL in filter manually and run this program. I can't get the correct data by doing this. 
I need to deselect all the countries and then I need to run.

**My Code**

```
Sub Addcountries()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim str1 As Variant
Dim Data As Variant
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim target As PivotTable

Set ws = Sheets("Main")
str1 = Application.InputBox("Enter the Country - comma separated")

If str1 = False Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter one Country", , "Filter Country"
    Exit Sub
Else
    If InStr(1, str1, ",") > 0 Then
        Data = Split(str1, ",")
        For i = LBound(Data) To UBound(Data)
            ws.PivotTables("MainTable").PivotFields("Country Code").PivotItems(Data(i)).Visible = True
        Next i
    Else
        ws.PivotTables("MainTable").PivotFields("Country Code").PivotItems(str1).Visible = True
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: not sure I understand, are you getting an error with this code ? or are you missing a feature ?

Comment: I think the problem is with the data that he is using in the Inputbox. And `Pivot Table` uses actual reference value from the excel and not from manual input. @Deepak : Did you tried using the excel for the input items?

Comment: @shai Im not getting error. I need to improve this code. I need to deselct all item in filter.

Comment: @Deepak you need to keep one, otherwisw you will get an error, which one you want to keep ?

Comment: @shai yes you are right. But i dont want to select 1 at first. Help me

Comment: @Deepak then what do you want to select ? you must have one

Comment: @shai, i didnt get u. What do u mean

Comment: @Deepak you can't deselect all items, once you try to deselect the last item, you will get a run-time error. Therefore, let me know which one you want to keep ?

Comment: @shai The user will enter 1 or more countries in inputbox. Then i need values only for that from pivottable. Do you have any other logic for that.

Comment: @Deepak I think I got what you are aiming for, see my answer and code below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through the `PivotItems` collection, and check each `PivotItem.Name` if it matches one of the selected countires inside `Data` array - you can accomplish that using the `Match` function.

**Code**

```
If str1 = False Then
    MsgBox "Please Enter one Country", , "Filter Country"
    Exit Sub
Else
    If InStr(1, str1, ",") > 0 Then ' more than 1 country >> create array
        Data = Split(str1, ",")
    Else ' single country
        Data = Array(str1) '<-- create array with 1 element (for Match to work)
    End If

    ' === You need a different loop, loop through all Pivot-Items, then look for a match with Data (array) ===
    Dim pi As PivotItem

    ' clear previous Filter
    ws.PivotTables("MainTable").PivotFields("Country Code").ClearAllFilters

    For Each pi In ws.PivotTables("MainTable").PivotFields("Country Code").PivotItems
        ' check if current Pivot-Item equals one of the elements of the array (use Match function)
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(pi.Name, Data, 0)) Then ' Match successful
            pi.Visible = True
        Else
            pi.Visible = False
        End If
    Next pi
End If

' rest of your code
```

Comment: your code is almost working. 2 Small problems. 1) when i am choosing 1 country its not working and still Selecting ALL. 2, When running the program for the second time i need to clear the filter. how to do that

Comment: @Deepak I wrote the code according to your post, I'll modify for the second option as well.

Comment: @ Now im getting error when i enter only 1 country. `unable to set the visible property of the pivotitem class`

Comment: At the end `pi.Visible = False`

Comment: @Deepak please check again, if you used the `ClearAllFilters` and the value entered in the `InputBox` exists as one of the `PivotItems, you should not get this error. This error will appear when trying to hide the last `Visible` Pivot-Items

Comment: Actually its working. But i need to enter one country with comma. Anyhow Thanks fo the code

Comment: @Deepak where should I send the bill ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

In order for your filter to work you need to give False Visible values to the Pivot Items you don't want to see as well as True Values to the one's you do so that you have set all the Pivot Items to True or False.

Here is some code to give you an idea;

```
Sub Addcountries()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim str1 As Variant
    Dim Data() As Variant
    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim target As PivotTable
    Dim PivotItem As Object
    Dim ShowMe As Boolean


    Set ws = Sheets("Main")
    str1 = Application.InputBox("Enter the Country - comma separated")

    If str1 = False Then
        MsgBox "Please Enter one Country", , "Filter Country"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If InStr(1, str1, ",") > 0 Then
            Data = Split(str1, ",")
        Else
            'Make Single Item Array
            ReDim Data(1)
            Data(0) = str1
        End If
        For Each PivotItem In ws.PivotTables("MainTable").PivotFields("Country Code").PivotItems
            'Default Visibility Is False
            ShowMe = False
            For i = LBound(Data) To UBound(Data)
                'Loop Through Each Item In Data To See If You Should ShowMe
                ShowMe = (PivotItem.Name = Data(i))
                If ShowMe Then
                    'Quit Early If You ShowMe
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
            PivotItem.Visible = ShowMe
        Next PivotItem
    End If

End Sub
```